# Fastest reimplementation PHP's htmlspecialchars function in C

Tags: php, c

I need the default behaviour (i.e `ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401`) of the PHP-function `htmlspecialchars()` in C, how is this done best (that means fastest) in C?

I don't need the input string, therefore an in-place solution is possible.

It is a really simple function, it just converts these characters:

```
'&' -> '&amp;'
'"' -> '&quot;'
'<' -> '&lt;'
'>' -> '&gt;'
```

What strategy would be fastest? Looping over each character individually and creating the output buffer byte-for-byte, overwriting the input string in-place or some other solution?

Comment: Allocate output with twice the size of your input and then resize it when necessary.

Comment: Also, you could simply check the actual [implementation](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/standard/html.c#1226) of that php function.

Comment: Fastest implementation depends on typical input characteristics. Is your typical input a few characters chunks or gigabyte-sized documents? How frequent are entities to encode? Do you have any memory constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assumes that input and output are buffers and that input contains the input string. It also assumes that the output buffer is large enough to hold the output (if not output is truncated):

```
long i = 0;
long j = 0;

while (input[i])
{
    if (input[i] == '<')
    {
        memcpy(&output[j], "&lt;", 4);
        j += 4;
    } else if (input[i] == '>')
    {
        memcpy(&output[j], "&gt;", 4);
        j += 4;
    } else if (input[i] == '"')
    {
        memcpy(&output[j], "&quot;", 6);
        j += 6;
    } else if (input[i] == '&')
    {
        memcpy(&output[j], "&amp;", 5);
        j += 5;
    } else
    {
        output[j++] = input[i];
    }
    if (j > sizeof(output)-7)
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
output[j] = 0;
```

In C, ugly code is often the fastest.

An in-place solution would only yield performance benefits if the characters to be exchanged would be very, very rare so that the whole string can be reordered (very expensive) on every character that is detected. With normal HTML-data, where these 4 characters will appear often, an in-place solution would be much slower.

Comment: How much memory would you allocate for `output`?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Well, if the function is used as intended (for HTML-formatted data), twice the memory of the input should be plenty. But thank's for the comment, I will remove that glaring buffer overrun in that code!

Comment: No issue. I was just asking. Since the comment from [@Jack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599597/fastest-reimplementation-phps-htmlspecialchars-function-in-c#comment47345814_29599597) was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a solution that works in both cases:

Calculates the required space and return an allocated string when `NULL` is passed, otherwise fill the passed string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static size_t encode_len(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = 0;

    while (*str) {
        if (*str == '"' || *str == '&' || *str == '<' || *str == '>') {
            len += 5;
        } else {
            len += 1;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return len;
}

static char *encode(const char *str, char *dest)
{
    char *ptr;

    if (dest == NULL) {
        dest = malloc(encode_len(str) + 1);
        if (dest == NULL) return NULL;
    }
    ptr = dest; 
    while (*str) {
        switch (*str) {
            case '"': memcpy(ptr, "&#34;", 5); ptr += 5; break;
            case '&': memcpy(ptr, "&#38;", 5); ptr += 5; break;
            case '<': memcpy(ptr, "&#60;", 5); ptr += 5; break;
            case '>': memcpy(ptr, "&#62;", 5); ptr += 5; break;
            default: *ptr++ = *str;
        }
        str++;
    }
    *ptr = *str;
    return dest;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Returns an allocated string */
    char *str = encode("testing & <> \"", NULL);
    if (str) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
        free(str);
    }

    /* Fills a passed string */
    char str2[128];
    encode("testing & <> \"", str2);
    printf("%s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you use the `encode_len` function even in a real world scenario? Wouldn't it being better to give a *good estimate*, probably twice the size of the input and the allocate more if you need more? I'm just asking...

Comment: @hek2mgl, that's the good thing about the dynamic memory, you should not worry about the length of the string (just consume what you need).

Comment: In this particular use-case (HTML comes usually in quite small chunks and not gigabytes of data), you could also just reserve 6 times of the length of the input and be a lot faster than trying to squeeze out every byte.

Comment: @RolandSeuhs, C is very very fast counting characters, `HTML comes usually in quite small chunks`, then why worry? any solution will be faster :)

Comment: @Alter Mann: Of course you are right that any solution will be fine, but of course it will be approximately twice as fast to go through the data only once instead of twice. So it's a tradeoff between speed and memory consumption.

Comment: @RolandSeuhs, edited in order to support both versions

Answer (score 0):

Here is `htmlspecialchars` function safe implementation.

---

## Info

- `char *_output` is the result.
- `size_t outlen` is the maximum number of bytes allowed to write to `_output`.
- `char *_input` is the string to be HTML escaped.
- `size_t inlen` is the length of string to be escaped (excluding null terminator).

This function returns the number of bytes written to `_output`, including null terminator.

**Note:** This function always puts null terminator to the `_output`.

---

## Code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define likely(EXPR)   __builtin_expect(!!(EXPR), 1)
#define unlikely(EXPR) __builtin_expect(!!(EXPR), 0)

/*
 * `char *_output` is the result.
 *
 * `size_t outlen` is the maximum number of bytes allowed to write to `_output`.
 *
 * `char *_input` is the string to be HTML escaped.
 *
 * `size_t inlen` is the length of string to be escaped (excluding null
 *  terminator).
 *
 * This function returns the number of bytes written to `_output`, including
 * null terminator.
 *
 * Note: This function always puts null terminator to the `_output`.
 *
 */
size_t htmlspecialchars(char * restrict _output, size_t outlen,
                        const char * restrict _input, size_t inlen)
{
    struct html_char_map {
        const char      to[8];
        const uint8_t   len;
    };

    static const struct html_char_map html_map[0xffu] = {
        ['<'] = {"&lt;",    4},
        ['>'] = {"&gt;",    4},
        ['"'] = {"&quot;",  6},
        ['&'] = {"&amp;",   5},
    };


    size_t j = 0;
    uint8_t len = 0;
    unsigned char * restrict output = (unsigned char *)_output;
    const unsigned char * restrict input  = (const unsigned char *)_input;
    const unsigned char *in_end = input + inlen;

    while (likely(input < in_end)) {
        const unsigned char *cp;
        const struct html_char_map *map_to = &html_map[(size_t)*input];

        if (*map_to->to == '\0') {
            cp  = input;
            len = 1;
        } else {
            cp  = (const unsigned char *)map_to->to;
            len = map_to->len;
        }

        if (unlikely((j + len - 1) >= outlen))
            break;

        memcpy(&output[j], cp, len);
        j += len;
        input++;
    }

    if (likely(outlen > 0)) {
        if (unlikely((j + 1) > outlen))
            j -= len;
        output[++j] = '\0';
    }

    return j;
}


int main(void)
{
    size_t len;
    char output[0xff];
    const char input[]  = "<a href=\"https://www.google.com\">Google</a><<>>";
    const char expected_output[] = "&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.google.com&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;&lt;&gt;&gt;";

    /* Input length (without null terminator) */
    size_t input_len = sizeof(input) - 1;

    /* Max allowed write bytes */
    size_t output_size = sizeof(output);

    len = htmlspecialchars(output, output_size, input, input_len);

    /* `len` includes null terminator char */
    printf("Written bytes to output: %zu\n", len);

    /* `output` */
    printf("output = %s\n", output);

    assert(!memcmp(output, expected_output, sizeof(expected_output)));
}
```